# JSON to tree diagram

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON object which is heavily nested. Is there a way in which I could view a hierarchical tree diagram? I went through several resources like Pydot, Plotly etc but nothing could render the JSON in my format.

JSON file:

```
{
  "found_intents": {
    "_DATE": {}
  },
  "sentence": "What is your name",
  "tree": [
    [
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_START_TAG",
        "correct_string": "<start>",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "<start>",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "<start>",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              0,
              1
            ],
            "span_string": "<start>",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "<start>",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          0,
          1
        ],
        "span_string": "<start>",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_WHAT_IS",
        "correct_string": "what is",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "what",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "what",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              1,
              2
            ],
            "span_string": "what",
            "weight": 1.0
          },
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "is",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "is",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              2,
              3
            ],
            "span_string": "is",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "what is",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          1,
          3
        ],
        "span_string": "what is",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_DICTIONARY",
        "correct_string": "your",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "your",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "your",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              3,
              4
            ],
            "span_string": "your",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "your",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          3,
          4
        ],
        "span_string": "your",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_DICTIONARY",
        "correct_string": "name",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "name",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "name",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              4,
              5
            ],
            "span_string": "name",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "name",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          4,
          5
        ],
        "span_string": "name",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_END_TAG",
        "correct_string": "<end>",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "<end>",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "<end>",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              5,
              6
            ],
            "span_string": "<end>",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "<end>",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          5,
          6
        ],
        "span_string": "<end>",
        "weight": 1.0
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_START_TAG",
        "correct_string": "<start>",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "<start>",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "<start>",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              0,
              1
            ],
            "span_string": "<start>",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "<start>",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          0,
          1
        ],
        "span_string": "<start>",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_WHAT_IS",
        "correct_string": "what is",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "what",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "what",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              1,
              2
            ],
            "span_string": "what",
            "weight": 1.0
          },
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "is",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "is",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              2,
              3
            ],
            "span_string": "is",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "what is",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          1,
          3
        ],
        "span_string": "what is",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_DICTIONARY",
        "correct_string": "your",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "your",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "your",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              3,
              4
            ],
            "span_string": "your",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "your",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          3,
          4
        ],
        "span_string": "your",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_THEATRE_ID",
        "correct_string": "name",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "name",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "name",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              4,
              5
            ],
            "span_string": "name",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "name",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          4,
          5
        ],
        "span_string": "name",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_END_TAG",
        "correct_string": "<end>",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "<end>",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "<end>",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              5,
              6
            ],
            "span_string": "<end>",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "<end>",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          5,
          6
        ],
        "span_string": "<end>",
        "weight": 1.0
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_START_TAG",
        "correct_string": "<start>",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "<start>",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "<start>",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              0,
              1
            ],
            "span_string": "<start>",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "<start>",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          0,
          1
        ],
        "span_string": "<start>",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_WHAT_IS",
        "correct_string": "what is",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "what",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "what",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              1,
              2
            ],
            "span_string": "what",
            "weight": 1.0
          },
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "is",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "is",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              2,
              3
            ],
            "span_string": "is",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "what is",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          1,
          3
        ],
        "span_string": "what is",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_THEATRE_ID",
        "correct_string": "your",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "your",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "your",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              3,
              4
            ],
            "span_string": "your",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "your",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          3,
          4
        ],
        "span_string": "your",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_DICTIONARY",
        "correct_string": "name",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "name",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "name",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              4,
              5
            ],
            "span_string": "name",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "name",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          4,
          5
        ],
        "span_string": "name",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_END_TAG",
        "correct_string": "<end>",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "<end>",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "<end>",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              5,
              6
            ],
            "span_string": "<end>",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "<end>",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          5,
          6
        ],
        "span_string": "<end>",
        "weight": 1.0
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_START_TAG",
        "correct_string": "<start>",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "<start>",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "<start>",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              0,
              1
            ],
            "span_string": "<start>",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "<start>",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          0,
          1
        ],
        "span_string": "<start>",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_WHAT_IS",
        "correct_string": "what is",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "what",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "what",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              1,
              2
            ],
            "span_string": "what",
            "weight": 1.0
          },
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "is",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "is",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              2,
              3
            ],
            "span_string": "is",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "what is",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          1,
          3
        ],
        "span_string": "what is",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_THEATRE_ID",
        "correct_string": "your",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "your",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "your",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              3,
              4
            ],
            "span_string": "your",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "your",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          3,
          4
        ],
        "span_string": "your",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_THEATRE_ID",
        "correct_string": "name",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "name",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "name",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              4,
              5
            ],
            "span_string": "name",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "name",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          4,
          5
        ],
        "span_string": "name",
        "weight": 1.0
      },
      {
        "canonical": null,
        "concept": "_END_TAG",
        "correct_string": "<end>",
        "definition": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "canonical": null,
            "concept": "",
            "correct_string": "<end>",
            "definition": "",
            "details": [],
            "e.g.": [],
            "grammar": "<end>",
            "language": "english",
            "span": [
              5,
              6
            ],
            "span_string": "<end>",
            "weight": 1.0
          }
        ],
        "e.g.": [],
        "grammar": "<end>",
        "language": "english",
        "span": [
          5,
          6
        ],
        "span_string": "<end>",
        "weight": 1.0
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

More precisely, I'd like to extract the average number of branches per level.

Expected results would be:

```
Level 0: 4  
Level 1: (1 + 2 + 1 + 1)/4  
Level 2: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you're trying to do, but the following code counts the number of dicts and lists at each nesting depth. We use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) as a stack to perform a breadth-first search, counting the number of nested containers at each level, storing the counts in a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists, and pushing those containers onto the stack for future processing. When we've finished counting all the objects we compute the mean number of branches at each level.

I won't paste your data into this code, since it's about 740 lines long. I refer to that data as `data_string`, on my machine I simply wrapped your data in triple-quotes, but of course you could save it as a file, and use `json.load` to load it.

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict, deque

data = json.loads(data_string)

def get_branches(obj):
    branches = defaultdict(list)
    stack = deque()
    stack.append((obj, 0))
    while stack:
        obj, depth = stack.pop()
        newdepth = depth + 1
        branch_count = 0
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            obj = obj.values()
        for child in obj:
            if isinstance(child, (list, dict)):
                branch_count += 1
                stack.append((child, newdepth))
        if branch_count:
            branches[depth].append(branch_count)
    return branches

branches = get_branches(data)
for depth in sorted(branches.keys()):
    row = branches[depth]
    mean = sum(row) / len(row) if row else None
    print('Level', depth, row, mean)
```

**output**

```
Level 0 [2] 2.0
Level 1 [4, 1] 2.5
Level 2 [5, 5, 5, 5] 5.0
Level 3 [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3] 3.0
Level 4 [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1] 1.2
Level 5 [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3] 3.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way I can get what portion of the entire json falls under the respective levels? One such instance would be self explanatory.

Comment: @nikinlpds That sounds like a good topic for a fresh question. ;) You can put a link in the new question back to this one, if you want. You'll need to explain exactly how you want to measure that. I assume you want it in terms of the number of nodes (items), but maybe you want to measure it in characters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Basically, whatever part of the JSON that falls in each level while traversing has to be fetched. I've made a separate question over here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189250/nested-json-get-elements-corresponding-to-each-depth. What I'm trying to do finally is see how many elements are present corresponding to say "concept" across each level.

Comment: @nikinlpds As bruno said, you need to explain your question more clearly, otherwise it will get put on hold.

Comment: Alright. I'll make it simpler. Currently we have the counts for number of dicts and lists at each nesting depth. I just want those dict/list as a whole to be extracted per level. Is it clear now?

Comment: @nikinlpds No, it's not clear now. But why are you putting that info here? You need to put further info into the body of your new question. Currently, it's being ignored because people can't tell what you want. But you probably saved yourself from getting downvotes because the question includes some code. If you show us a small sample of input data along with the exact expected output that matches that input then people will be able to help you. When you edit your question it will get bumped back to the front page, so many people will notice it.

Comment: I've added a diagram which could be helpful in understanding.